# MVC Update FormsAuthenticationTicket UserData at Runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am writing an **MVC 4** web application with **custom authentication and authorisation**. When a user logs into the site, I create a a **FormsAuthenticationTicket** and store it in a **cookie**

```
public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie, string UserData)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

    // Create and tuck away the cookie
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(15), createPersistentCookie, UserData);
    // Encrypt the ticket.
    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

    //// Create the cookie.
    HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
}
```

The **UserData** string will be a pipe delimited string and it will always contain at least two items, **UserID | UserRole**. A user can be assigned to one or more roles, therefore, the UserData could look like this **UserID | UserRole | UserRole | UserRole**

I then have my own custom **generic principal** in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        // Get the authentication cookie
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        // If the cookie can't be found, don't issue the ticket
        if (authCookie == null) return;

        // Get the authentication ticket and rebuild the principal
        // & identity
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        string[] UserData = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { '|' });

        GenericIdentity userIdentity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name);
        GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(userIdentity, UserData);
        Context.User = userPrincipal;
}
```

This all works fine, however, within my application, if a user has multiple roles, when they log in, I need to list their roles, and then let them select only one role to go and perform functionality based on the selected role.

I was thinking, to do this, maybe I could pass the role the user selects to a method, get their **FormsAuthenticationTicket** and update the **UserData** to reflect the role they have choosen. For example, a **UserData** string is created with **1|Manager|Applicant**, then I need to list both roles and ask the user which role they want to perform functionality under, they select **Manager** and I then update their **UserData** within their **FormsAuthenticationTicket** to **1|Manager**.

Is this even possible, or maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: That seems like very unintuitive behavior.  So the user has to log out and log back in to do other activities?  It's better just to let the user do what they're allowed to do and not make them jump through hoops.  That's just poor usability.

Answer (score 8):

You could always change `FormsAuthenticationTicket`.

```
HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(Username, true);
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

var newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,
                                              ticket.Name,
                                              ticket.IssueDate,
                                              ticket.Expiration,
                                              true, 
                                              "new user data",
                                              ticket.CookiePath);

cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
cookie.Expires = newticket.Expiration.AddHours(24);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, I feel this is very poor usability.  However, if you're determined to do this, then Dzenan's approach would work (you essentially just strip out all the other roles after the user has selected which role he wants).

Another approach would be to add an additional field to your userdata, which is SelectedRole.  Then create a custom IPrincipal that includes this field.

Another approach would be to store it as your own cookie, although I would make sure that you validate that you aren't setting a role that the user is not authorized for (ie if you set SelectedRole=Admin make sure the user has an Admin role before you use it).

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866994/mvc4-custom-authentication-solution thanks a lot !